# wilcoxon pvalue of 0

Tags: r

I am trying to use wilcoxon test to compare two vectors, even if there is a clear difference between them using summary() like shown below, I obtained a value of 0 that I don't know how to interpret, and it doesn't change anything if it is exact or not.

Can you please tell me more about it, and whether or not I have a bias somewhere and how to correct it ?

Thanks, my codes below.

```
> wilcox.test(F$V14,B1$V14,alternative="g",exact=F)$p.value
Error in exact && !TIES : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
> wilcox.test(F$V14,B1$V14,alternative="g")$p.value
[1] 0
> summary(F$V14)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    7.0    64.0   108.0   131.4   169.0   452.0 
> summary(B1$V14)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   3.000   7.000   9.781  14.000  61.000 
>
```

Comment: If you post the data itself (for example, using `dput(F$V14)`) it would make it a lot easier to explain (but in general it just means that it is very small)

Comment: You may have another variable named "F", try using FALSE instead

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to interpret a 0 p-value then you need to take an introductory statistics course and/or read an introductory text.

Basically the p-value is a measure of the consistancy between the null hypothesis and the data, large values (maximum of 1) indicate that the data is reasonably consistent with the null hypothesis, small values (near 0) indicate that the data and the null hypothesis are not consistent with each other.

A p-value of 0 means that your data is not consistent with the null hypothesis that the 2 samples come from the same population (or the less restrictive hypothesis that the probability that $A>B$ is $0.5$ when A is a random value from the 1st population and B is a random value from the second population).  The summary makes it clear that the data is not consistent with the null, the p-value just formalizes this.

Comment: It is not like I don't know how to interpret pvalues it is just I am wondering why the value is exactly 0. Thanks

Comment: It just means it is very, very small.